# Adding ImageViews to vertical layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have two image views, which I am trying to put into a vertical linear layout. I want them to be one on top of the other, but somehow they get placed horizontally. Here's my code:

```
String[] portalNiz;
Uri slika;
ImageView imgLogo = new ImageView(AllDiscounts.this);
portalNiz = c.getString(1).split("\\.");
slika = Uri.parse("android.resource://rs.jedanzasve/raw/"+portalNiz[0].toLowerCase());
imgLogo.setImageURI(slika);

Uri slikaKategorije;
ImageView imgCategory = new ImageView(AllDiscounts.this);
String categoryImage = "";
if (c.getString(14).contains("lepota")) categoryImage = "lepota";
if (c.getString(14).contains("odmor")) categoryImage = "odmor";
if (c.getString(14).contains("putovanja")) categoryImage = "putovanja";
if (c.getString(14).contains("ostalo")) categoryImage = "ostalo";
if (c.getString(14).contains("proizvodi")) categoryImage = "proizvodi";
if (c.getString(14).contains("sport")) categoryImage = "sport";
if (c.getString(14).contains("hrana")) categoryImage = "hrana";
if (c.getString(14).contains("bioskopi")) categoryImage = "bioskopi";
if (c.getString(14).contains("zdravlje")) categoryImage = "zdravlje";
slikaKategorije = Uri.parse("android.resource://rs.jedanzasve/raw/"+categoryImage.toLowerCase());
imgCategory.setImageURI(slikaKategorije);

LinearLayout vertikalniSlike = new LinearLayout(AllDiscounts.this);
vertikalni.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

vertikalniSlike.addView(imgLogo, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

vertikalniSlike.addView(imgTest, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the imageViews to vertikalniSlike LinearLayout but you have set orientation to verticalni layout. Unless is the typo. Please replace:

```
vertikalni.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

with

```
vertikalniSlike.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I was that blind. The problem is that there is also a "vertikalni" LinearLayout, and a "vertikalniSlike" LinearLayout - and I am pretty tired. Thank you for this

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a fresh pair of eyes...  :)